# Why this polynomial is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K=\mathbb{Z}_p(t)$. How to prove $f(x)=x^p-t$ is irreducible in $K[x]$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\mathbb Z_p[t]$? If not, could you define the construct you did indicate?

Comment: @Lubin $K=\mathbb F_p(t)$ is the field of rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb F_p$, the finite field with $p$ elements and $K[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in one variable over $K$. What's unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_p$ is a UFD ring, therefore so is $A = \mathbb Z_p[t]$. The polynomial $f(x) = x^p - t$ is monic so, because of Gauß' lemma, $f$ is reducible in $A$ iff it is reducible in $\mathrm{Frac}\, A = K[t]$.

But now, we can apply the [generalisation of Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization). We have a prime ideal $\mathfrak p =(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_t[x]$ which contains every coefficient of $f$ except the dominant one, and the constant coefficient $t$ doesn't belong to $\mathfrak p^2$. Therefore, $f$ is irreducible in $A$.

**Remark.**  If $p$ is a prime, on any field $F$, $f = x^p -a$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ unless it has a root in $F$. This is proved in Cox' *Galois Theory*, section 4.2.D.

Comment: Very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Use Eisenstein's criterion by recalling that $t$ is prime in $\mathbb Z_p[t]$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!